# CSS not working on 000webhost

Tags: html, css

I just started a simple website on 000webhost. I uploaded the following index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html lang="en">   
    <head>   
        <title>Tabs</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">        
        <meta name="description" content="Bootstrap."> 
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">   
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>  

<body style="margin:20px auto">  

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row header" style="text-align:center;color:green">

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a>Tab 1</a></li>
                <li><a>Tab 2</a></li>
                <li><a>Tab 3</a></li>
            </ul>

            <p><br></p>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Locally, and what I want it to show up as, is the following:
[What I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCoFP.png)

And then what is shows up as on webhost, is the following:
[Not what I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd0Sz.png)

It's not using the CSS/js scripts (bootstrap stuff) I added at the top of the page. Any idea why?

Comment: Check your network inspector in the browser. Are all your assets loading correctly?

Comment: tbh I'm very new to this stuff, and I'm not sure how to check if my assets are loading correctly. here's the website: https://temptry.000webhostapp.com/. edit: ok, the chrome developer tools, under console, it says the scripts/sheets are insecure and not loaded. any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the console for errors!

You're viewing your 000webhost page on `https` (secure), so it's not loading the assets that you're calling hardcoded on `http` (insecure).

You can either view your site over http to see everything loaded: http://temptry.000webhostapp.com/

Or, more preferably, fix your references to your assets to be https-agnostic (leading with `//`), or point directly to https. For example:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: The double slash is really a better way to plug these things in. Fewer chances for mix-ups, especially if you're testing locally first.

Comment: @tadman Mixups can always happen, but as of 2014, Paul Irish recommends always using `https://` and calls the double-slash an anti-pattern: https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

Comment: @JonUleis He's entitled to his opinion, of course, but that's just one opinion of many.

Answer (score 1):

It's your cache, clear your cache and it will work.
Or you can wait until your computer reads the new changes. It can take up to 24 hours depending on your cache settings.

To clear your cache using Chrome:

1. Open settings
2. Search for "cache"
3. Click "Clear browsing data"
4. Change the range if it is not working
5. Click "Clear data"

Good luck.

[Demonstrate picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGSMs.png)

Comment: This answer is relevant for today!